# How to find x-values of fourier-transformed correlation functions in velocity space?

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, spectra, python, velocity

I am trying to extract the kinematic parameters (rotation velocity, velocity dispersion, ...) of an elliptical galaxy by extracting the kinematical broadening function using the FCQ-Algortihm first described by Bender 1990: (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990A%26A...229..441B/abstract)

I am therefore using the central line spectra of the elliptical galaxy NGC 4697 and the 1D template spectra of the K2-III star HD 132345. After some preprocessing steps I calculated the cross correlation function between the galaxy and the template and extracted the peak of it.

[image][image]

I calculated the velocity spacing per pixel and the velscale is approximately 30 km/s per pixel. I

Now I have to transform the peak of the correlation function into fourierspace:

```
from numpy.fft import fft as fourier, ifft as ifourier
corr_gal_tem_peak_fourier = np.fft.fftshift(fourier(corr_gal_tem_peak))
```

The plotted resulting powerspectrum (absolute square) in fourierspace has the expected gaussian form, plotting it leaving out the x-values like:`plt.plot(np.power(np.abs(corr_gal_tem_peak_fourier), 2))` results in:
[image]

I now need to fit a model for this powerspectrum to create an optimal Wienerfilter in fourierspace. I therefore need some x-values in fourierspace. I tried to create x-values using np.fft.fftfreq() with:
`n = corr_gal_tem_peak.size s = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=velscale)`
Plotting this idea results in this:[image]
Can anybody tell me how to properly create the array for the x-values in fourierspace, they would have unit of s/km ?

Comment: have you tried using [fftshift](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html)? From the last plot it looks like your frequency array is sorted in a different way than your porwerspectrum array

Comment: Thank you very much with fftshift it is working.  But I am not sure if I approached it right in general ?